# sql data reader getting empty when ever i want to use it

Tags: c#

i really need your help iam working on a school project.
i use SqlDataReader to store my data, after storing the data (and it works i checked it while debugging the sqldatareader result view is full of my data) when i try to use the sqldatareader Variable that has all the data it directly becomes empty ?? 
before getting to the if line my sqlreader has all the data in it but when i debug the if line its shows that the sqlreader is empty !

```
 class ServicesProvider
    {
     public static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myprovider);
      public static bool LogInVerification(string NickName,string Password)
        {
            SqlDataReader SqlReader;
            SqlCommand command;
            try
            {
                command = new SqlCommand("Check_LogIn", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter prm=null;
            prm = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            prm.Value=NickName;
            prm.Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters.Add(prm);

            prm = new SqlParameter("@NickName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            prm.Value=Password;
            prm.Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;
            command.Parameters.Add(prm);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (SqlReader["NickName"].ToString()== "1")
                return true;;
            }
            catch (Exception ERROR)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ERROR.Message);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
SqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (SqlReader["NickName"].ToString()== "1")
```

When `ExecuteReader` returns, the reader is located *before* the first result. You need to call `Read` to read the result. Typically that would be:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{ 
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Handle the data for this row
    }
}
```

Notes:

- If you only want to read a single value, consider using `ExecuteScalar`
- You should have a `using` statement for each disposable resource (the connection, the command, the reader)
- Local variables are conventionally camelCased (not PascalCased like `SqlReader`)
- Using a single static connection is a really bad idea. Create the connection and open it each time you want to perform a database operation, and dispose it when you're done with that operation (which will happen automatically with a `using` statement)
- It *looks* like you're probably storing passwords in plain text. This is obviously a *huge* security problem.

Comment: @Mostafa Sarsour : mark it as answer by choosing the 'check' mark above .